# Лаги при управлении змейкой с экрана андроид(при работе в виртуалке unity лагов нет)

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class HandlerScript : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler
{
    public static int xx = 1;

    public static int yy = 0;


    public  void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        int x = MainGameScript.Dx;
        int y = MainGameScript.Dy;


        MainGameScript.Dx = 0;
        MainGameScript.Dy = 0;

        if (Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.x) > Mathf.Abs(eventData.delta.y))
        {
            if (x == 0)
            {
                if (eventData.delta.x > 0)
                    xx = 1;
                else
                    xx = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                xx = x;
            }
            yy = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (y == 0)
            {
                if (eventData.delta.y > 0)
                    yy = -1;
                else
                    yy = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                yy = y;
            }
            xx = 0;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }
}
```

код скрипта который лежит на Panel в Canvas, при игре на телефоне часто нет реакции на движение пальцем или она некоректна(поворачивает не в ту сторо), при работе на комп - все нормально

Comment: может проблема из-за высокой нагрузки на процессор телефона?

Comment: Посмотрите сколько на вашем телефоне оперативной памяти, перед запуском отчистите все процессы и проверьте если лаги остались то дело в коде если нет то проблема в телефоне

Comment: Проблема в отсутствии реакции скорей всего в onBEGINdrag, может отрабатывает только при начале движения(пальцы толще чем указатель мыши, threshold разный). Поворачивает не в ту сторону, на некоторых телефонах нарушена ориентаци экрана( перевернута, там где на компе верхний левый, на телефоне нижний левый и т.д ) Ну либо в коде проблема( не разберешь за что отвечает x и y)

Comment: очень интерестно, на одном телефоне samsung все норм, другой sony иногда меняет ориентацию осей координат и не реагирует на движение пальцем. Раньше думал что проблема в методе который передвигает ячейки змейки (затормаживается получение координат вектора движения ), но вродь проблема в самом телефоне(